# Find the greatest odd number with a limited number of bits

Tags: java, algorithm

I was trying to solve this question but the automated judge is returning "time limit exceeded" (TLE).

On the occasion of Valentine Day , Adam and Eve went on to take part in a competition.They cleared all rounds and got into the finals. In the final round, Adam is given a even number N and an integer K and he has to find the greatest odd number M less than N such that the sum of digits in binary representation of M is atmost K.

Input format:

> For each test case you are given an even number `N` and an integer `K`

Output format:

> For each test case, output the `integer M` if it exists, else `print -1`

Constraints:

- 1 ≤ T ≤ 10<sup>4</sup>
- 2 ≤ N ≤ 10<sup>9</sup>
- 0 ≤ K ≤ 30

Sample input:

```
2  
10 2  
6 1
```

Sample output:

```
9 
1
```

This is what I have done so far.

```
    static long play(long n, int k){
      if(k==0) return -1;
      if(k==1) return 1;
      long m=n-1;      
      while(m>0){                      
              long value=Long.bitCount(m); //built in function to count bits
              if(value<=k ){                  
                  return m;
              }
              m=m-2;          
      }     
        return -1;
    }

    public void solve(InputReader in, OutputWriter out) {
       long start=System.currentTimeMillis(); 
       int t=in.readInt();
       while(t-->0){                
          long n=in.readLong();         
          int k=in.readInt();
          long result=play(n,k);         
          out.printLine(result);
       }
       long end=System.currentTimeMillis();
       out.printLine((end-start)/1000d+"ms");       
    } 
 }
```

Comment: Ok, what is the result? What is the sample input ? What is the result ? Do you want us to test this code?

Comment: I said i m getting Time limit Exceed. What else should i do so that i will get accepted.

Comment: @Suresh: Here you go. Testing it directly on hackerrank against this challenges test cases is easier: https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/codenigma/challenges/love-with-numbers

Comment: So what is Eve doing?

Comment: @Andreas probably eating an apple ... well apparently Adam is weak in Math & needs Eve's help.. hence the program.

Comment: @Kavita aren't you supposed to find the sum of the bits? You are just counting the bits here, aren't you?

Comment: @hermit Same thing.  `11000111`: count 1's = 5, sum all = 5. `bitCount` "Returns the number of one-bits"

Comment: @Andreas I thought Long.bitCount() counts zeros too..my bad

Comment: I like the fact that `N` is an **even** number between 2 and **109**.

Comment: @Andreas I read the problem description and submitted an edit.. N is between 2 and 10^9 O_O

Comment: @sid Thanks for editing. I never posted any question before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to updated question `N` can be between 2 and 10^9. You're starting with `N-1` and looping down by 2, so you get up to about `10^9 / 2` iterations of the loop. *Not good*.

Starting with `M = N - 1` is good. And using `bitCount(M)` is good, *to get started*. If the initial bitcount is `<= K` you're done.

But if it's not, *do not* loop with step `-2`.

See the number in your mind as binary, e.g. `110101011`. Bit count is 6. Let's say K is 4, that means you have to remove 2 bits. Right-most bit must stay on, and you want largest number, so clear the two second-last 1-bits. Result: `110100001`.

Now, you figure out how to write that. And do it without converting to text.

**Note:** With `N <= 10^9`, it will fit in an `int`. No need for `long`.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to perform bitwise operations to compute the answer quickly. Let me give you a few hints.

The number 1 is the same in binary and decimal notation: 1<sub>2</sub> = 1<sub>10</sub>

To make the number 10<sub>2</sub> = 2<sub>10</sub>, shift `1` to the left by one position. In Java and many other languages, we can write this:

```
(1 << 1) == 2
```

To make the binary number 100<sub>2</sub> = 4<sub>10</sub>, shift `1` to the left by two positions:

```
(1 << 2) == 4
```

To make the binary number 1000<sub>2</sub> = 8<sub>10</sub> shift `1` to the left by three positions:

```
(1 << 3) == 8
```

You get the idea.

To see if a bit at a certain position is 1 or 0, use `&`, the bitwise AND operator. For example, we can determine that 5<sub>10</sub> = 101<sub>2</sub> has a 1 at the third most significant bit, a 0 at the second most significant bit, and a 1 at the least significant bit:

```
5 & (1 << 2) != 0
5 & (1 << 1) == 0
5 & (1 << 0) != 0
```

To set a bit to 0, use `^`, the bitwise XOR operator. For example, we can set the second most significant bit of 7<sub>10</sub> = 111<sub>2</sub> to 0 and thus obtain 5<sub>10</sub> = 101<sub>2</sub>:

```
7 ^ (1 << 1) == 5
```

Comment: ,Thank you very much.

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help. Could you accept my answer, please?

Answer (score 0):

As the answer is odd,

let ans = 1, here we use 1 bit so k = k - 1;

Now binary representation of ans is

```
ans(binary) = 00000000000000000000000000000001

while(k > 0):

     make 30th position set
     ans(binary) = 01000000000000000000000000000001
     if(ans(decimal) < N):
          k -= 1
     else:
          reset 30th position
          ans(binary) = 00000000000000000000000000000001
 Do the same from 29th to 1st position
```